# Facebook graph "/me/photos" endpoint requiring 'Page Public Content Access'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We've had a facebook app which access the authorized user's photos. It uses user tokens.

It had been working for a long time. In the last few days, requests to the graph endpoint `me/photos` has started giving us an error stating the endpoint requires 'Page Public Content Access'. I can also reproduce this in the graph explorer. Note: it only occurs if I refresh user token, the older tokens seem to work.

We're not attempting to access a public page so this error doesn't seem to make sense. We're only accessing the "me" page and the user token has the user_photos permissions.

Is this error a facebook bug? Do we need to change how we call the graph? Do we need this permission (would prefer to not request it since it doesn't sound applicable to a user-token based app accessing "me" page).

Thanks in advance.

Exact API and error can be seen below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Weird glitch, and one I can’t personally reproduce.

(And even if the token *was* a page token, that error would not make sense. `/me` with a page token automatically resolves to the page the token is for, so this *could not* be “public access” to begin with.)

There’s already a bug report for this, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/315161742450138/ - though it is currently in “needs more info” status. Maybe subscribe to that, then you will get updated when there’s anything new on this. And you can also comment there, if you have info to add.