# Facebook permissions changed. User_photos no longer sufficient. 'Page Public Content Access' addition

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a function that gets the list of user photos and their urls.

This has been working 100% fine for months. This morning my client is spamming me asking why thousands of users cannot select Facebook photos :-|, we have a big user base.

Even worse new users are crashing because of the Facebook pre-filling photos method we have. Luckily we can CodePush to insta-fix this and not wait for Apple.

Anyhow, all of a sudden this API request is no longer working. I had no email, nothing from Facebook wtf?

Does anyone know of an alternative way to get user photos without this permission? (It's a very annoying long process to get permissions). I can't seem to find it in the junk that they call the Graph Explorer.

Below we can see the permissions that have always worked fine.

[image]

And the said function

```
export const getListOfUniqueFacebookPhotoUrls = () => {
    return new Promise<Array<string>>((resolve, reject) => {
        const graphRequestConfig: GraphRequestConfig = {
            httpMethod: 'GET',
            version: 'v3.1',
            parameters: {
                fields: {
                    string: 'images',
                },
            },
        }
        const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
            '/me/photos',
            graphRequestConfig,
            (error: any, data: any) => {

                if (error) {
                    Logger.log('Error getting Facebook requests', error)
                    reject(error)
                    return
                }

                if (!data) {
                    Logger.log('Error getting Facebook no data')
                    reject(error)
                    return
                }

                // Got photos, array of urls.
                const imageUrls: Array<string> = []
                data.data.forEach((eachDataChunk: any) => {
                    if (eachDataChunk && eachDataChunk.images[0] && eachDataChunk.images[0].source) {
                        imageUrls.push(eachDataChunk.images[0].source)
                    }
                })

                resolve(imageUrls)
            }
        )
        new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start()
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to read the photos from user profiles, or from pages? The error message rather only makes sense when it’s the latter.

Comment: Using the user_photos permission how would I know and what would the request look like?

I'm doing the following which should be valid from my request https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos

Comment: Ah now I remember, this seems to be a current bug, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332114/facebook-graph-me-photos-endpoint-requiring-page-public-content-access/54342261#54342261